# How to stop sending log error mail which already sent, only new error should be send

Tags: linux, weblogic

below is the log, I want only unique error lines out of 10 lines in which what error line sent exclude those one.

```
cat oacore_server9_error.log
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:42:53 AM IST> <Error> <ServletContext-/OA_HTML> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '40' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <000001VgZDn8dpG5IzL6if01wG68000149> <1567660373961> <BEA-000000> <chain failed
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:43:18 AM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '61' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1567660398800> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '80' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "1,856" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 1856503 ms
WatchRule: (SEVERITY = 'Error') AND ((MSGID = 'WL-000337') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-000337'))
 SUBSYSTEM = WebLogicServer USERID = <WLS Kernel> SEVERITY = Error THREAD = [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '61' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' MSGID = BEA-000337 MACHINE = test@example.com TXID =  CONTEXTID =  TIMESTAMP = 1567660398800
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:44:18 AM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '78' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1567660458814> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '80' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "1,916" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 1916517 ms
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:47:08 AM IST> <Error> <ServletContext-/OA_HTML> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '22' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <000001irEO28dpG5Izg8yf01b00U00006p> <1567660628368> <BEA-000000> <chain failed
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:48:18 AM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '75' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1567660698870> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '82' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "1,805" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 1805188 ms
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:48:18 AM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '75' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1567660698877> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '20' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "1,833" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 1833065 ms
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:49:18 AM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '56' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1567660758908> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '82' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "1,865" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 1865226 ms
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:49:18 AM IST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '56' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1567660758912> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '20' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "1,893" seconds working on the request "Workmanager: default, Version: 0, Scheduled=true, Started=true, Started time: 1893103 ms
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:51:29 AM IST> <Error> <ServletContext-/OA_HTML> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <000001ySOBy8dpG5IzL6if01wG680003mJ> <1567660889829> <BEA-000000> <chain failed
####<Sep 5, 2019 10:55:46 AM IST> <Error> <ServletContext-/OA_HTML> <test@example.com> <oacore_server9> <Thread-24815> <<anonymous>> <> <000002C0mW38dpG5IzL6if01wG680004BJ> <1567661146719> <BEA-000000> <CGIServlet: CGIServlet failed to write body for the response
```

below is the code I used:

```
cd $EBS_DOMAIN_HOME/servers/oacore_server9/logs
OACORE_SERVER1_FILE="$EBS_DOMAIN_HOME/servers/managed_server_errors/oacore_server1_error.log"
oacore_server1_v=`tail -5000 oacore_server1.log|grep BEA | grep -i error| uniq -u |  tail -1 | wc -l`
if [ $oacore_server1_v -ge 0 ]; then
tail -5000 oacore_server1.log|grep BEA | grep -i error | uniq -u > $OACORE_SERVER1_FILE
if [ `cat $OACORE_SERVER1_FILE | wc -l` -gt 0 ] ; then
  cat "$OACORE_SERVER1_FILE" | mailx -s "ALERT:Oacore Server Error Alert in log file of oacore_server1 on ${host}  at `date`" "$EMAIL_ADDRESS"
fi
fi
```

When I grep BEA and error i am always getting old error lines plus new lines, i want unique lines/error only and which already sent that should be excluded while greping new error.

Comment: Read how to format your question and do it.

Answer (score 0):

any linux admin please try to help.

Answer (score -1):

A better way should be to use [WLDF](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLDFC/intro.htm#WLDFC107) to send emails when new errors appear in server's log. Read this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13714/config_watch_notif.htm#WLDFC188) about configuring watch and notifications.

Comment: Please try to help to fix my script as i mentioned.